# Does JavaScript garbage collect this?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Every once in a while I find myself doing something along the lines of the following

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'php/getpic.php?z=' + imid + '&th=0';
img.onload = function(){drawImages(img,contexts,sizes)};
```

Explanation

1. Create an HTML image element.
2. Assign its src attribute
3. Assign its onload event
4. Pass one or more Canvas contexts to the event handler
5. Draw the loaded image to the canvases

The thing I am not clear about is this - will the JavaScript garbage collector deal with the task of discarding the img element or do I need to do it myself or else face a slooow memory leak?

Comment: Aside: Swap steps 2 and 3. If the image is cached, IE will fire `onload` before the assignment `onload = function() {}` executes.

Comment: DrawImages should not be too relevant here - it simply draws the image that  has been loaded on to one or more canvases (passed as contexts in the last line) that are in the DOM. Once that is done the img object has no further use.  The images are never cached in this instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *will leak* in **IE 6 and 7** (and very old versions of FF) because it creates a circular reference between JavaScript and the DOM. IE 6 and 7 can't garbage collect any objects which have circular references between the two worlds because they use separate garbage collectors.

Modern browsers can handle this without leaking.

To prevent it from leaking in IE 6 and 7, do this when you're done with `img`:

```
img.onload = null;
```

If you only care about modern browsers, you don't have to worry about it. (I'm so glad IE 6 and 7 are finally low enough in market share to suggest that!)

---

### Update

The function you assign to `onload` creates a closure. That closure contains a reference to `img`. `img` can't be garbage collected from the DOM's memory as long as that closure exists in JScript's memory (JScript is name for the IE implementation of JavaScript). Likewise, the closure can't be garbage collected from JScript's memory as long as `img` exists in the DOM's memory, because `img.onload` has a reference to your function. This is a circular reference. In other words, just because `drawImages` executes once doesn't mean it won't execute again (the JScript engine doesn't know `onload` only fires once -- that's the DOM's domain), so JScript has to keep the closure alive.

The pattern you have shown is the classic pattern that is known to create memory leaks in IE 6 & 7. It consists of (1) A DOM node, (2) An event handler on that DOM node which creates a closure, and (3) A reference back to that DOM node inside the closure.

Comment: The bit that is not clear to me is this - in my case I am NEVER adding the newly created img element to the DOM.  I use it to fetch the image resouce from the server, then use the loaded image to draw on to one or more canvases at which point I am done with it.  The only reference left to it is the parameter passed to drawImages which I imagine becomes eligible for garbage collection as soon as that function has returned.

Comment: @DroidOS, I have updated my answer to try to explain it better. Cheers.

Comment: @DroidOS, another important thing I want to point out is that just because you don't add the element to the *document*, it's still a DOM component, and garbage collection of that object is done through the DOM's garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations, Nathan.  I haven't gotten around to looking at what happens via the Chrome Heap Debugger yet but plan to do so tomorrow.  I guess I don't particularly care about IE and certainly not the prehistoric versions so any IE specific issues are reasonably safely ignored.

Comment: In that case, don't worry about it. You don't have a memory leak in modern browsers.

Answer (score 6):

If you are worried about memory leak what I suggest you is to use the [Heap Debugger of Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling). In your case I have made a simple test that can verify if your particular pattern will create a memory leak.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test() {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'php/getpic.php?z=1&th=0';
                img.onload = function(){ drawImages(img,contexts,sizes); };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I recommend you to press "test" once before the test to avoid unnecessary noise in the result (there are thing which get added in the memory the first time the code runs and this doesn't mean there's memory leak).

Take a heap snapshot, press test and take a heap snapshot. If you want the actual result you have to switch the view from "Summary" to ["Comparaison"](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling#views_comparison). If the view is empty (in your case when I tested), it means nothing was added during the step, which mean that it doesn't have memory leak. In the other case, it will show you what was added or deleted between the snapshot.

Note : This method won't help you with memory leak for older browser that have their own issue, but it's a good step to find thing that will cause memory leak in most modern browser.

Comment: Thank you for the Heap Debugger tutorial - I will try it out and get back here later.

Comment: I finally did some extensive testing with Heap Debugger.  The good news - no memory leaks!